# Behaviour of Python when attempting to iterate over characters in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, for-loop, iteration

I am attempting to iterate over the following string, using a `for` loop:

```
>>> for a,b,c in "cat"
        print(a,b,c)
```

Now what I intended for this to do was print out each character in the string individually on one physical line, instead I receive an error. I am aware that this is very easily resolved by enclosing the string in the list operator `[]`:

```
>>> for a,b,c in ["cat"]
        print(a,b,c)
c a t
```

But could someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: Why are you using *three* variables to receive the loop value into? You only have **one** character each iteration.

Comment: It was an experiment to see if I could print the string on one physical line, without modifying the print statement with `end=" "` @MartijnPieters

Comment: But then you are not looping, are you? Just use `a, b, c = 'cat'`. Or just print the string as separate arguments with `print(*'cat')`.

Comment: To clarify: I wanted to print/output the string on one physical line with the use of a for loop. Idle curiosity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are telling `for` to expand each iteration value to assign to three separate variables:

```
for a,b,c in "cat":
#   ^^^^^ the target for the loop variable, 3 different names
```

However, iteration over a string produces a string with a single character, you can't assign a single character to three variables:

```
>>> loopiterable = 'cat'
>>> loopiterable[0]  # first element
'c'
>>> a, b, c = loopiterable[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

The error message tells you why this didn't work; you can't take three values out of a string of length 1.

When you put the string into a list, you changed what you loop over. You now have a list with one element, so the loop iterates just once, and the value for the single iteration is the string `'cat'`. That string just *happens* to have 3 characters, so can be assigned to three variables:

```
>>> loopiterable = ['cat']
>>> loopiterable[0]  # first element
'cat'
>>> a, b, c = loopiterable[0]
>>> a
'c'
>>> b
'a'
>>> c
't'
```

This still would fail if the contained string has a different number of characters:

```
>>> for a, b, c in ['cat', 'hamster']:
...     print(a, b, c)
...
c a t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

`'hamster'` is 7 characters, not 3; that's 4 too many.

The *correct* solution is to just use **one** variable for the loop target, not 3:

```
for character in 'cat':
    print(character)
```

Now you are printing each character separately:

```
>>> for character in 'cat':
...     print(character)
...
c
a
t
```

Now, if you wanted to pass all characters of a string to `print()` as separate arguments, just use `*` to expand the string to separate arguments to the call:

```
>>> my_pet = 'cat'
>>> print(*my_pet)
c a t
```

Answer (score 3):

The `for` loop goes through each element in the iterable you supply and tries to perform an assignment.

In the first case, since your iterable is `'cat'` you're essentially unpacking:

```
a, b, c = 'c'
```

during the *first* iteration and getting the appropriate error message:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

because you'll iterate *3 times*; once *for each character in the string* `'cat'`.

In the second case, you're unpacking `"cat"` as expected, because the list *has a single element* (i.e `'cat'`) which is retrieved and unpacked into `a, b` and `c`.

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating different objects in two blocks of code.
In the former one, you iterate the string, which may be considered a `special list`.

While in the latter one, you iterate the `list` which contains only one object 'cat'.

You may change the first one to below:

```
for ch in 'cat':
    print(ch)
```

Feel free to ask more about this.